# How to get jQuery validate error class in the input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, validation, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery validate plugin and I am running into an issue with how the error messages are displayed. From looking in the developer tools I found that the error message is `.error`, so I am trying to modify this. I am wanting the error message to display within the input of the field that didn't pass the validation. As you can see in my code, I am wanting the error to be on the right side.

I am doing this for the error:

```
.error {
    color: red;
    display: inline !important;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
label.error {
    /*margin-left: 10%;*/
    right: 5%;
}
```

I tried doing this instead of the `label.error`

```
input.error {
   /*margin-left: 10%;*/
   right: 5%;
 }
```

But it didn't help.

Please let me know if I can add more info to this question.

Comment: Show the relevant **rendered** HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

add your style

```
.error {position : absolute}
```

End then put margin and padding it to where you want

Update answer

In your site, you should edit html like below

```
<form action="" autocomplete="on" method="POST" id="project-information-form" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="input-borderless error" id="title-roll" name="title" placeholder="Title/Role" aria-required="true">
        <label id="title-roll-error" class="error" for="title-roll">Please enter your title</label>
    </div>
...
```

Then you set style `.input-group {position : relative}` and `.error {position : absolute}`

If you don't want bound your `input` and your `error` to one div, you need calculate your `input` position by javascript. And in your javascript, you set position for `.error` element. But I think that way is effortless

Comment: Didn't help. I've tried that. It bunches all of my inputs and error messages together.

Comment: you have to bound your input and your error to one div.

Comment: I've update my answer as a suggestion. It quite simple, hope you can understand my idea

Comment: you need add some css style for make `.error` more beautifully

Comment: It still just bunches everything together. Take a look